Order latex refrences by order of .bib file?
I'm writing a latex script (in overleaf) and I need the references in text to appear using \citep, but at the same time, I want the References (\bibliography{bibliography}) to follow the imported .bib file. Now, if I use  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}, I get the order of appearances as in .tex file, but this doesn't work for me. If I use \bibliographystyle{plainnat}, it seems to work somewhat, but there are croatian letters (which I had to write as \v{z} instead of ž etc.) and some accented letters which throws everything off (e.g. surname starting with accented A is the last on the list???). The .bib file contains ~350 entries, over 4500 lines...
I figure I can sort the issue using Jabref, and then just print the references as the appear in .bib file, but I can't seem to figure how? Using \bibtex and \printbibliography just times out overleaf...
Any help? Thanks!
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{times}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\arial}{Arial}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{currvita}
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage[round]{natbib}


\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}
\usepackage[breaklinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction} \setcounter{page}{1}
bla bla bla text \citep{example}.


\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}


N.B. - \nocite{*} because I need references which do not appear in the main .tex file

you have fontspec  so must be using luatex or xetex so never use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} or  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

just use nocite{*} first before your other cite.

what font do you want? You use the deprecated times package to specify Times Roman, then over-erite that with lmodern which re-specifies latin modern which is the default font in lualatex and xelatex, so you could simply delete both of those packages

YES!!! \nocite{*} before first cite WORKS!!! Thank you so much!!!

As for the font, my first two custom titlepages should be Arial, and the rest of the text should be Times New Roman - because university still uses word as default. I have managed to do so, but I have trouble including letters like č, ć, š and ž directly from keyboard, so I was trying to figure it out with the packages.

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every post, even in the original one. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78840839/2777074

You are not getting times roman as you have specified latin modern. the characters you mention you can simply enter as characters in th emain document or in bibtex use {\v c} not \v{c}

Instead of reprimending me for a question you failed to answer, just as I was going to repost the answer on first page, maybe try to add contstructive criticism. Thanks.

@ljeonjko better than linking to the cross post would be not to cross post

@ljeonjko I didn't fail to answer your question, I suggested the same solution as David https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78840839/order-latex-refrences-by-order-of-bib-file#comment139002952_78840839 an hour ago

loading packages that break the the latex character support (eg \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} in xelatex will not solve any problems, only generate them. You should remove most of the packages you list in this example.

Apologies, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I miunderstood your comment as to try to compile without the nocite command first to see if the code works. Apologies once again for lashing out!

Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I have removed the support packages, seems to be in good order now.

Just use \nocite{*} first before your other cite.
